# How to solve the equation in algebraic number theory?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, finite-fields, primitive-roots

First step: When $p\equiv 1 \pmod{ 3}$, prove that there exists a pair $(a,b)$ of integers such that $4p=a^2+27b^2$, $a\equiv 1 \pmod{ 3}$ and a is unique [(the proof of the first step)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_reciprocity).

Second step: Prove that $x^3+y^3=1$ has $p-2+a$ solutions in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

For the second step, we know that in $\mathbb{F}_p^*$, $\ \exists g\ $ s.t. $\mathbb{F}_p^*=\{g,g^2,\dots,g^{p-1}(=1)\}$. Hence $\{x^3|x\in\mathbb{F}_p^*\}=\{g^3,g^6,\dots,g^{p-1}\}$ is the unique subgroup of index 3 in $\mathbb{F}_p^*$. But I don't know the relation between the solution of the equation and the decomposition $4p=a^2+27b^2$.

Any ideas?

Comment: $a\equiv\pm1\pmod 3$ so replacing $a$ by $-a$ if necessary, we can assume $a\equiv1\pmod3$.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_reciprocity may help with the first part, under the “integers” tab

Comment: It may well happen that $a$ is negative. A case in point is $p=13$, when $4p=(-5)^2+27\cdot1^2$ and the number of solutions is $6=13-2-5$. Namely $$(x,y)\in\{(0,1),(1,0),(0,3),(3,0),(0,9),(9,0)\}.$$

Comment: Have you checked out Ireland & Rosen? They have a reputation of covering bits like this! I would begin with the chapter on Jacobi sums.

Comment: Anyway, this is an elliptic curve, though in a slightly unusual orientation, and consequently there are three points on the line at infinity (due to the existence of third roots of unity). We expect $p+1$+ an error term coming from the trace of the Frobenius minus the points at infinity. That explains $p-2$, and $a$ should be related to the trace. Obviously $|a|\le 2\sqrt p$, so Hasse-Weil and all that jazz.

Comment: Mind you, I think the question was more convincing with your proof for the first part included. The link is fine, I suppose (and should also stay).

Comment: From [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: There is a standard method for this in Section 8.3 of *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory*.